# If $A = \{x\mid12 < x < 15\}$ and the universal set is the set of positive real numbers less than $15$, what is the complement of $A$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to answer in set builder notation. I put $A^c = \{x\mid 0 \lt x \le 12\}$. I feel that was too easy. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.

Comment: @DanZimm, how does your hint help? $16\not\in A$ and $16\not\in A^c$.

Comment: @AJStas I failed to read correctly, my apologies

Comment: @theguy1991 Set of positive real numbers up to 12.

Comment: @RioAlvarado: Especially at this elementary level, you should _not_ edit the OPs notation from $\{x\mid \text{blah}\}$ to $\{x:\text{blah}\}$, since there's a good chance he will only be familiar with the variant he knows. (At less elementary levels the harm is less, but you still shouldn't change notation from what the OP prefers to _your_ personal preference without a good reason).

Comment: Tis a fair point. I shall note it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything.

The correct answer $\{x\mid 0<x\le 12\}$ may also be written more compactly as $(0,12]$ or $]0,12]$.